# Developer Story is a nice thing, but why is it not visible in mobile web view?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, mobile-web

The story view of Developer Story is an awesome thing and should be in mobile web view.

[image]

Comment: Workaround: scroll to the bottom of the page and [click "full site"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFxwt.png) to see the site in desktop mode.

Comment: The developer story page isn't responsive, which is probably the reason there isn't a link. It looks bad on mobile, which is disappointing for something that's supposed to be externally visible - I like how [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/story/kobi) turned out, but there are places where I avoid posting the link because I know there is a *risk* of the page looking bad.

Comment: "The developer story page isn't responsive" :O what? are we in the 20th century? Does this mean I cannot easily check someone's story on my phone during a conference/talk?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão [Responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) is the concept of having a page whose layout changes based on the dimensions of the browser viewport to maximize usability for all browsers and devices. What kobi means is that the page layout when displayed in a mobile browser does not differ from what is displayed in a desktop browser, leading to a less usable page when viewed on a mobile browser.

Comment: They should hire a Frontend developer :))