# Developer Story looks poorly readable on mobile

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

My developer story came up in conversation at the conference and I opened it on my phone.

Result looked about like this (screenshot generated with Chrome dev tools):

[image: mobile screenshot]

They were highly unimpressed. :) Could use some responsive love.

Comment: Looks like a timeline layout to me

Comment: Was it supposed to look different? My main point is that it was tiny/unreadable.

Comment: No, I misread your question. I think it was asked before though https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342100/developer-story-is-a-nice-thing-but-why-is-it-not-visible-in-mobile-web-view

Comment: Saw it, I think the discussion there is on the same issue, but the question itself seems different to me (though related).

Comment: @Rarst Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: All of SO could use some responsive love.

Comment: @NathanArthur for the questions there is a very nice app that makes it highly useable. Unless you want to delete-vote.